Touch Screen Panel of Car Radio Set-up
The Touch Screen of Car Radio Setup was damaged and removed. HD 6.95 INCHES WIDE SCREEN TFT (HG-070) A capacitance touch screen was replaced with the IC GT911 6Pin. Its working good except the Icon on the LEFT needs touching on the RIGHT side of the panel and vice versa. The original IC denotes HC-36GT911 but the item replaced cannot be read. It is a GT911 as per the supplier. What should I do?

are you saying that you removed a touch screen and installed an IC in its place?
